# Spring Roo Video Player

Tags: spring, video, media-player, spring-roo

I want to play a video in my web application. İs there any short way to play theese video in my web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create and use your own custom tag which supports video -- with the video url passed as a parameter for a flash based or html5 video player.